# How to write 'unless' statement

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

Here is my code:

```
puts "Enter number"
score = gets.chomp.to_i
unless (score>=10) 
  puts "you are freshmen"
unless (score<=11) && (score>=20)
  puts "You are sophomore"
unless (score>=30) && (score<=21)
  puts "You are Junior"
else 
  puts "You are Senior"
end
```

I want to use only one `unless` statement. How can I do this?

Comment: just missing the `end`.

Comment: I've already inputted and end, but still it didn't worked sir

Comment: `unless ... end`, please count yours.

Comment: The whole snippet just makes no sense. You misunderstand in general how `unless` works. `unless (score<=11) && (score>=20)` is never evaluated to `false`, neither do others.

Comment: I've edited my problem now sir. sorry for being unclear sir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are abusing `unless`. The whole code should be written as:

```
puts "Enter number"
score = gets.chomp.to_i
puts case score
     when 0..10 then "you are freshmen"
     when 11..20 then "You are sophomore"
     when 21..30 then "You are Junior"
     else "You are Senior"
     end
```

<sup>yeah, there is no life after 30</sup>

---

Just in case of demonstration purposes (please never use this at home or school)—`unless`-only version:

```
puts "Enter number"
score = gets.chomp.to_i
puts "you are freshmen" unless score > 10
puts "You are sophomore" unless (score > 20 || score <= 10)
puts "You are Junior" unless (score > 30 || score <= 20)
puts "You are Senior" unless score <= 30
```

Comment: I'm done with the case statement sir, now what I'm trying to do now is to write an unless statement in other words, I want to convert that into unless statement.

Comment: I have updated an answer, but please, do not do that in real projects.